# How do you pass variables to jsc/javascript?

Tags: osx, variable, javascript

I have a few javascript things that I am running from the Terminal by passing them to `jsc`, with `<<<`. (`javascript` is an alias to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc`).

However, I need to pass variables there, for example `$1` or `$2`, I tried

```
javascript <<< rand="$1" && ....
```

But it's obvious that javascript doesnt understand those variables. When I pass other varibales, it says this.

```
$ variable=something
$ javascript <<< "variable2=$variable && alert ("$variable2");"
Exception: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: variable
undefined

$
```